# Trouble Gettting JavaBeans to write to XML

Tags: java, xml, javabeans

My code writes the name to the XML document but it does not write any of the test scores. The test scores always output 0 even when I change the name. I would greatly appreciate any help in figuring out why that is the case. I have attached the class with the main method and the class with the constructor. Thank you for the help!

```
import java.beans.XMLDecoder;
import java.beans.XMLEncoder;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Studentp194Runner {

public static void main(String[] args)
{           
    Studentp194 s1 = new Studentp194();

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter student name: ");
    s1.setName(reader.nextLine());
    System.out.print("Enter the student's first score: ");
    s1.setScore(1, reader.nextInt());
    System.out.print("Enter the student's second score: ");
    s1.setScore(2, reader.nextInt());
    System.out.print("Enter the student's third score: ");
    s1.setScore(3, reader.nextInt());

    try
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("./student.xml"));
        XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(fos);
        encoder.writeObject(s1);
        encoder.close();
        fos.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    try
    {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("./student.xml"));
        XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(fis);
        Studentp194 p2 = (Studentp194)decoder.readObject();
        decoder.close();
        fis.close();
        System.out.println("Student 1 name: " + p2.getName());
        System.out.println("Test 1: " + p2.getScore(1));
        System.out.println("Test 2: " + p2.getScore(2));
        System.out.println("Test 3: " + p2.getScore(3));

    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

}

```
public class Studentp194 {
//instance variable
private String name;
private int test1;
private int test2;
private int test3;

//constructor method

public Studentp194()
{

}

public Studentp194(String name, int test1, int test2, int test3)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.test1 = test1;
    this.test2 = test2;
    this.test3 = test3;
}

//Other Methods

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setScore(int i, int score){
    if (i == 1)
        test1 = score;
    if(i == 2)
        test2 = score;
    else
        test3 = score;
}

public int getScore(int i)
{
    if (i == 1)
        return test1;
    if (i == 2)
        return test2;
    else
        return test3;
}

public int getAverage()
{
    int average = (int)Math.round((test1 + test2 + test3) / 3);
    return average;
}

public int getHighScore()
{
    int highScore = test1;
    if(test2 > highScore)
        highScore = test2;
    if(test3 > highScore)
        highScore = test3;
    return highScore;
}

public String toString()
{
    String str = "Name: " + name + "\n" + 
                 "Test 1: " + test1 + "\n" +
                 "Test 2: " + test2 + "\n" +
                 "Test 3: " + test3 + "\n" +
                 "Average: " + getAverage();
    return str;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortest possible answer that is technically correct but useless to someone not familiar with Java beans: `Studentp194` does not have a `score` property.  Therefore the non-existent `score` property is not encoded to XML by `XMLEncoder`.

To really understand what's going on, if you want to continue to use `XMLEncoder`, which may or may not be the best solution for the real problem you are trying to solve, you have to read up on the staggeringly ancient but (IMHO) terrific [Java Beans specification](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/).

For any arbitrary class to have a Java Beans property named, say, `foo`, whose type is `Foo`, then it has to have a `public Foo getFoo()` method and a `public void setFoo(Foo foo)` method.  As you can see, your `Studentp194` class does not have a `public int getScore()` method, nor does it have a `public void setScore(int score)` method.

(Of course, the Java Beans specification does not actually mandate that these are the required names of your methods.  You can customize them in a number of ways, including the usage of [`BeanInfo` classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html), but that is well beyond the scope of this question.)

Getting back to your question and your code, `XMLEncoder` won't help you here with your class design as-is since your `getScore` method takes parameters, and your `setScore` method takes more than one parameter.  Therefore they are not Java Beans properties; therefore `XMLEncoder` is not going to, well, encode them.

Let's say you wanted for whatever reason to continue using `XMLEncoder`.  Then you'd have to refactor your class to conform to the Java Beans specification.  I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.  :-)

I'm guessing this is some kind of assignment, and that using `XMLEncoder` is a requirement of the assignment.  If I'm wrong, then look at a different file format for storing your information and retrieving it.

If I'm right, then you want to look at the fact that your `Studentp194` class is logically associated with a *collection* or array of scores.  You may want to look in the direction of actually creating a class to represent a test score, and storing a collection of such test scores in your `Studentp194` class.  Even better yet, perhaps your `Studentp194` class wants to be related to another class like `Transcript` or something similar where this information could be stored properly.  For more on this decompositional approach to breaking down problems, read up on "third normal form" and go from there.  I hope this helps and welcome to StackOverflow.